# Swapping an object into an image using Javascript onload

Tags: javascript, rest, html, json

I have a JavaScript page which is querying a SharePoint list. I'm getting the result of column called DevicePriority which is either Red, Amber or Green. The results are returned to a HTML page. I need to change these to the relevant jpgs eg  ://xxx.com/IT/SiteAssets/amber.png

To do this I think I'll need a onload function with an if statement, so

```
<body onload="imageswap()">

<script>
if DevicePriority = "Red" 
 {
Don't know what condition to put here?
  } 
</script>
```

Do I place this in the JavaScript or the HTML? Both codes below:

JavaScript

```
function getDeviceDetails() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtOverview = "";
var txtAccessories = "";
var txtDevicetype = "";
var txtTypicalDeviceUsage ="";
var txtKnownSystemIssues ="";
var txtLifeCycles = "";
var txtTrafficlight = "";

var tempLCS2 = "";

var query = "http://collaboration-xxxx/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=LifeCycleStatus&Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";

var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;




         var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;
        var LifeCycleStatus = item.LifeCycleStatusValue;
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        var AccessDetails = item.Accessories;
        var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype;
        var Usage = item.TypicalUsage;
        var DevicePriority = item.PriorityValue;

        txtTitle = "<p>" + LifeCycleStart + "</p><p>" + LifeCycleStatus  
+ "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
        txtAccessories = "<p>" + AccessDetails + "</p>";  
        txtDevicetype = "<p>" + DeviceKind  + "</p>";
        txtTypicalDeviceUsage = "<p>" + Usage + "</p>";
        txtTrafficlight = "<p>" + DevicePriority + "</p>";

    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('#devicekind').append(txtDevicetype);
    $('#deviceacc').append(txtAccessories);
    $('#deviceuse').append(txtTypicalDeviceUsage);
    $('#devicestatus').append(txtTrafficlight);


});

  call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

}

HTML

```
 <html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"  
  xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
  <script src="/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script 
 src="/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDevices.js"></script>
 <script  
   src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceDetails.js"></script>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     function parseQueryString(queryString)
    {
    var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;
    queries = queryString.split("&");
    for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        temp = queries[i].split('=');
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
   }
return params;
 }

  $(document).ready(function(){
function getDeviceID() {
    if(typeof parseQueryString === "function") {
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
            var qs = parseQueryString(window.location.href.split("?")[1])
            window.DeviceId = qs.did;
            getDeviceDetails();
            getDeviceKnownIssues();
        }
       }
}
getDeviceID();
    getDevices();
```

});

```
 <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
 <mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">ITDOCUMENTS-135-47</mso:_dlc_DocId>
 <mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">1d6007ea-9e58-4298-b2d6-
   9196e2678ea3</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>

 <mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">http://collaboration-
  dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?  
 ID=ITDOCUMENTS-135-47, ITDOCUMENTS-135-47</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
 </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
 </xml><![endif]-->
 </head>
 <style type="text/css">
 .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
 .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;padding:10px     
   5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-  
   break:normal;}

.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}


 </style>
 <table>
 <table class="tg">
  <tr>

<td rowspan="3" class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Devices</h2>
 <div id="devices"></div>



 </td>


<td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Devise Details</h2> 

<div id="devicedetails">
    </div></td>


    <td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Specification</h2>

 <div id="deviceoverview">
     <div id="devicekind">   
    </div></td>




   </tr>
   <tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Known Issues</h2> 
  <div id="knowntitle">
      </div> 
      <input type=button onClick="location.href='http://collaboration-
     XXX.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/Lists/Knownissues/NewForm.aspx?
     Source=http%3A%2F%2Fcollaboration%2Ddev%2Enorgine%2Ecom%2Fsites%2Fit%
     2FSystemInventory%2FLists%2FKnownissues%2FAllItems%
     2Easpx&RootFolder='" value='Submit a known issue '> 


       </td>



   <td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Accessories </h2> 
 <div id="deviceacc"></div></td>
```

```
<td colspan="2" td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Typical Usage</h2>
```

```
<td colspan="3" td class="tg-yw4l" width="100"><h2>Current Status</h2>
```

```
</table>
```

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to do? Are you displaying multiple devices in one and based on device click you are showing device details with image or what?

Comment: No, basically it's a RAG status column. So if a user selects Red, Amber, or Green in the column choice of SharePoint (Priority) is shows the relevant coloured jpg on the HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you can make following change in your code.

HTML
Add a container for your image holder, e.g. `<div id='imageContainer'></div>`, where you want to display the image.

JS
After getting the data of `DevicePriority` just call the following statement:

```
$('#imageContainer').append("<img src='url_to_web/SiteAssets/" + DevicePriority + ".png' />");
```

Just make sure, the value DevicePriority gives is the name of you image without extension and the extension is hard-coded as `.png`.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it should work, I've put      $('#imageContainer').append("<img src='/IT/SiteAssets/" + DevicePriority + ".png' />");   but nothings coming up. I've added the div tag to the HTML...

Comment: I changed the + DevicePriority to + txtTrafficlight and an image is showing up but as the x place holder and when I look at the properties it's: http://collaboration-xxx.com/IT/SiteAssets/%3Cp%3EAmber%3C/p%3E.png

Comment: Are you using rich text formatting in column? Because it is adding `<p>` tag around the data. If so use RegEx to remove the extra tags.

Comment: Use following js code. `txtTrafficlight.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');`. And if it does solve your problem then please mark the answer. :)

Comment: also add a `.trim()` function to remove white spaces around the data.

Comment: It hasn't, but that may because I copied it wrong. I'm putting in: $('#imageContainer').append("<img src='/IT/SiteAssets/"+txtTrafficlight.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')+".png' />");

Comment: Cheers, a bit of jiggery pockery and I got it working